# Opening link using Intent.ACTION_VIEW caused android.content.ActivityNotFoundException on certain device(s)

Tags: android

Recently I started getting `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:` for my app logged on Google Play Console. Codes causing this exception are :

```
private void openLink(String url) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now the exception is rarely happened, it works fine on most of devices, and the url is 100% valid (a link to https://mathsolver.microsoft.com/).

My question is what caused them and what is the best way to handle them.

Is a simple try catch enough or there is way so that user that catch this exception can still open the url from their phone?

Comment: "and the url is 100% valid" -- what sort of URL is this? "what caused them" -- for example, if the URL is `http` or `https`, the user might not have access to a Web browser. Restricted profiles, work profiles, etc. can limit what apps the user has access to.

Comment: @CommonsWare a link to https://mathsolver.microsoft.com/

Comment: OK, apparently the affected users do not have access to a Web browser. That is uncommon but definitely happens. Catch the `ActivityNotFoundException` and apologize to the user that you cannot open a Web browser for them.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes it's rarely happens like 1 in 10K sessions or so. I guess try catch and message it is, can you put that as answer so that I can mark this problem as soved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are starting an activity that is from another app — such as a Web browser — you have to take into account that the user might not have access to such an app. Even something as common as a Web browser might be restricted on some devices (e.g., devices used by children).

As such, you need to wrap such `startActivity()` calls in a `try`/`catch` block and deal with `ActivityNotFoundException`. Exactly *how* you deal with it will be up to your app, but you will need to explain to the user that you are unable to start the desired app for some reason.